# Firebase & Pyrebase can't write to database with Authentication

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, pyrebase

I am farely new to Pyrebase and Firebase and I was wondering why this code isn't working.
I want to write to the realtime database, for that the rules are

```
{
  "rules": {
    "userdata": {
      "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
        }
    }  
}
```

And the python code is:

```
def login():
    email = input("Enter email: ")
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
    user = auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])
    uid_variable = user['userId']
    print(uid_variable)
    print("Successfully logged in!")
    data = {"test": "test"}
    db.child("userdata").child(uid_variable).set(data)
```

But when it tries to write to the database it shows:

```
 [Errno 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://xxxxxxxxxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/userdata/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json] {
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

I don't seem to find any help anywhere so anything would be appreciated!

Comment: I am struggling on the same point. It looks like pyrebase is not unable to perform correct authentication on Firebase. If I change the rules for your database to let everyone reads, it works perfectly, but if I set to only authenticated user, it denies reading.

Comment: I made a very simple test by ".read": "auth.uid == null", (which means the pyrebase is not authenticated and I could read everything. I set to ".read": "auth.uid != null",. then it denies. I think this is an issue with pyrebase authenticating process.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're using with your backend, this post on how to integrate Firebase Auth with a FastAPI backend using Pyrebase and Firebase Admin shows how you can create a [login with Pyrebase using username and password](https://pythonalgos.com/python-firebase-authentication-integration-with-fastapi/#login-pyrebase-fastapi)

Based on the code here:

```
@app.post("/login", include_in_schema=False)
async def login(request: Request):
   req_json = await request.json()
   email = req_json['email']
   password = req_json['password']
   try:
       user = pb.auth().sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
       jwt = user['idToken']
       return JSONResponse(content={'token': jwt}, status_code=200)
   except:
       return HTTPException(detail={'message': 'There was an error logging in'}, status_code=400)
```

I believe you need to call the `auth()` function with the pyrebase object you created.